# lightbox : bug on combining a set of related images

Tags: html, carousel, lightbox

need help to combine a set of related images.

I have a group of related images that i would like to combine into a set, i use the same data-lightbox attribute value for all images i want to include in that set, so the visitor can easily browse them with "prev" and "next" arrows.

BUT it's not working, am able to see allimages out of this set.

HERE my codes

```
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <a href="images\marketing\diapo\2\01.jpg" class="lightbox d-inline-block" title="" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
                                <img src="images\marketing\diapo\2\01.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <a href="images\marketing\diapo\2\03.jpg" class="lightbox d-inline-block" title="" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
                                <img src="images\marketing\diapo\2\03.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>
                        </div>


                          <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <a href="images\marketing\diapo\3\01.jpg" class="lightbox d-inline-block" title="" data-lightbox="roadtrip2">
                                <img src="images\marketing\diapo\2\01.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <a href="images\marketing\diapo\3\02.jpg" class="lightbox d-inline-block" title="" data-lightbox="roadtrip2">
                                <img src="images\marketing\diapo\2\03.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
```

When click on first gallery, i want to see in lightbox only the 2 set of images in this group and when click on the second gallery , i see only the images in the second group.

HELP pls

Comment: It would be great if you edited your question, add a snippet where the problem reproduces.